# AS3 how to return EventListener value

Tags: actionscript-3

If I have code that looks like this:

```
public function getNetStreamPublishClientList():Array
{
    var ncStreamListResults = new Object()
    ncStreamListResults.onResult = function(list:Array)
    {
        //this needs to be returned from getNetStreamPublishClientList
        return list;
    }

    this.nc.call("getStreamClientIds", 
                 new Responder(ncStreamListResults.onResult),
                 this.streamName);
}
```

how can I return the value of list from `getNetStreamPublishClientList`?

Answer (score 0):

use global item for list

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you won't be able to know the value of `list` at the point that `getNetStreamPublishClientList()` finishes executing.

This is because the `nc` object will probably not have finished its work by that time, and in that case the completion handler (currently assigned to be `onResult`) won't have been called.

Whatever is waiting on the result of this function, I'd change it to wait for an event.  Possibly use a member function to act as the `onResult` handler.